# How to link multiple rows within a single table - MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm looking into a way on how I can link multiple rows within a single table.

In short, this is a system in which users can add messages. Messages are linked to a division. A user can post a message to multiple divisions at once.

The messages are stored multiple times in the messages table. So when I send my message to 3 divisions it creates 3 rows in the messages table.
The reason this is done is because per divisions users can comment on messages. In different divisions the comments will also be different.

A new request came in to be able to link those messages. To keep it simple a messages can me marked as 'done'. When this messages is marked as 'done' in division 'a', the others messages (the 2 other rows) in division 'b' and 'c' also need to get this mark.

Currently I have not a single clue on how to do this in a good way.
I've had the idea of creating an extra table containing the message id but still not sure on how I would get all the linked messages from it.

Having one message as a 'parent' came across my mind. And then searching for childs and parent messages on every change. But this doesn't feel like a good solution.

Really looking forward to some suggestions to help me in the right direction!

Comment: If the message is the same and always will be (in all divisions) it might make more sense to have a separate table for these message. Give them each a unique id that can be stored the original table and used to reference the message. This would be a better normalized database management approach that will eliminate redundancy of having a possibly large text blob stored in several rows.

Comment: This looks like a pretty simple many to many, with Division, Message, and DivisionMessage. Comments go in DivisionMessage, while Done is on Message.

Answer (score 0):

Split `messages` into two tables; I will call them `m1` and `m2`:

`m1` has all the columns that remain constant across all divisions.  That probably includes the bulky text of the message.  Let's have `PRIMARY KEY(m_id)`.  `m_id` could be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  It sounds like `done` needs to be in this table.

`m2` has one row per division, so, it has a copy of `mid` and the `division_id`, so probably `PRIMARY KEY(mid, division_id)` (or possibly in the opposite order).  Also in this table are any columns that are different among the divisions.

m1:m2 is a 1:many relationship, as implemented via `m_id`.  And that column would be used for `JOINing`.

It sounds like "comments" are per-division.  So a `comment` (wherever it is) would have both `m_id` and `division_id` in it.

Comment: The only problem with this is, the messages are most likely the same across the multiple divisions they are posted in but they CAN be edited. The edit might only apply to a single division. 

The solution you mentioned would indeed be perffect if the message would always be the same across the division.

Comment: @Maarten - So, an Edit is not replicated to the other divisions, but a "done" is?  You have a mess.

Comment: Sounds crazy I know. Client requirements are far from logic but that's just how the organization works (or at least how they want to work).

Comment: @Maarten - I would push back on "done" not accounting for editing of messages.  This smells like a design flaw that they did not think of.  They might even pat you on the back for pointing out the flaw and fixing it in the system.